# Load an Ember.js app from another website

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm working on a project where I'd like to load an Ember.js application from another website, hosted on a different server and using a different domain name. In other terms, I'd like to include an Ember app in other website like I would do with an iFrame, but without an iFrame.

I built my Ember.js application using Yeoman and the Ember generator.

In the origin website, I just have a simple markup like this:

```
<body>
    <h1>My website</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    <div id="myEmberApp"></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</body>
```

I know how to call an external JS file, but don't know from here how to execute or to load my Ember.js app. I tried also with CORS, but I don't think it will suit my needs.

For the records, I can't use an iFrame. On the origin website, I don't want to have any dependencies against jQuery or whatever. In the future, I'd like to be able to offer a step by step how-to to integrate this app on any websites.

Is there any solution? Or should I have to plan to do my app in full JS without Ember.js?

Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks in advance

--- Edit ---

Here's how I call my JS file from the origin website:

```
<!-- The JS script to be included by the client -->  
<script>

  (function () {
    var eh = document.createElement('script');
    eh.type = 'text/javascript';
    eh.async = true;
    eh.src = '//localhost:9000/scripts/edenhome.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(eh, s)
  })();
</script>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I am missing something, but why not just include your application in a script tag? I'm not familiar with the yeoman generator, but most of these build tools kick out an ember application with templates precompiled into JavaScript functions and then all your files concatenated together in a single file.

For example:

```
// this would be the precompiler output generated by yeoman, not exactly like
// this, but same idea, the template is part of the JS file
Ember.TEMPLATES['application'] = Ember.Handlebars.compile('<h1>I am an ember app</h1>');

// make an app and set the rootElement
var App = Ember.Application.create({
  rootElement: '#myEmberApp'
});
```

You can see here I'm loading in the ember app from a different domain:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mawuv/1/edit

**edit follow up**

Injecting the script works just as well as a script with a src attribute:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mawuv/2/

Comment: Hi Ryan,

Thanks for the answer.

Basically, I'm trying to include an Ember app in another website without using an iFrame. The idea is to use a solution inspired by the way we integrate things like Google Analytics or UserVoice on our websites.

The problem is that when I call my JS file from the origin website, Ember is not instantiated.

I edited my post to include the call to the JS file.

Let me know if you need more information.

Cheers,

Comment: Hi Ryan

I think it's getting clearer. Now the only problem I can see is that the origin website still has to include jQuery, Handlebars and Ember in its source. That's what I don't want. Do you think it might be possible?

In addition, do you think the Ember app can play with the URL and that we can use the URL to launch the app in a defined state? For example, if my app returns a list of items, if I click on one, it gives http://origin.com/mypage.html/#/items/1 and if I reload the page, the Ember app will go straight to item 1?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following,

*disclaimer: i have not actually tried what you are asking, but i do usually load everything from separate files but within the context of the same domain.*

1. create a function that loads all templates and appends them to the document.
2. create a function that runs the complete ember.js app.
3. create the file that will be referenced by the remote site and will search for a specific element (this could also be parametrized / be a jquery plugin etc) and once found loads all templates calling function from *(1)* and start the application calling function from *(2)* with `rootElement` the specific element mentioned earlier. *(Prior to any of the previous loadings, all dependencies of the ember.js app should be loaded e.g. jquery, handlebars.js, ember.js etc. probably in a no conflict state)*
4. All ajax requests to the server from the ember app should be carried out using `jsonp`.

simplified example,

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nelosese/1/edit

**js**

```
/*it is possible to load templates from independent files, using promises, however here it is just demonstrated the loading of templates*/
/*a callback is added since they are loaded async and only when this is done should the app complete initialization */
function initTemplates(callback){
  var templates ='<script type="text/x-handlebars"><h2> Welcome to Ember.js</h2>{{outlet}}</script><script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index"><ul>{{#each item in model}}<li>{{item}}</li>{{/each}}</ul></script>';
  $('body').append(templates);
  callback();
}

function initApp(){
  App = Ember.Application.create({
    rootElement: '#myEmberApp'
  });
  App.Router.map(function() {});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({model: function() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
  }
});
}

/*a reference to your bootstrap script, that executes the following*/

$(document).ready(function(){

if($('#myEmberApp').length>0){
      $.get("/",function(){initTemplates(function(){
        initApp();
      });});

}

});
```

**html**

```
<body>
  <div id="myEmberApp"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Hello, 

Thanks for your answer.

If I understand your solution, the problem is that the ember.js file must still be included in the origin website. In my mind, the only operations that must be made on the origin website is a simple copy and paste of a piece of Javascript and inserting the div where you want to display the application.

How can I achieve that? Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @LionelRudaz that's exactly what i described copy paste a link to a javascript via `<script src="...../your-bootstrap-app-script.js" />` and add a `div` in the content with the specified id. Then the script will load/inject the dependencies of the ember app ie jquery.js, handlebars.js, ember.js etc and then templates along with your app. I split the items conceptually, it would be best to have them possibly in one minified file. I usually break them in two one minified with all external lib dependencies and another with all the app related.

Comment: OK I think I got you. So basically, in my bootstrap script, I will call all the JS files independently. Makes sense. Thanks a lot.